# Load all rows in csv file - Python

Tags: python, numpy

I want to load a csv file into python. The csv file contains grades for a random number of students and a random number of assignments.

I want python to delete the header and the first column (Name of student) and this is my code:

```
with open("testgrades.csv") as f:

ncols = len(f.readline().split(','))
nrows = sum(1 for row in f)
grades = np.loadtxt("testgrades.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=range(1,ncols+1))
print(document1)
```

The code works for columns but can't handle if I add one or more rows in the csv file?

My CSV file:

[csv](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1ebAg.jpg)

And output from Python:

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZcBVk.jpg)

Comment: Please show a few lines of your CSV and your expected output along with what actually happens if you run this code. Also, the indentation is not correct, you should fix that.

Comment: what's the use of computing `nrows` ? and it should work. input & expected output are required here...

Answer (score 0):

Your `csv` image looks like a messed up spread sheet image.  It isn't a copy of the `csv` file itself, which is plain text.  You should be able to copy-n-paste that text to your question.

The `Output` image is an array, with numbers that correspond to the first 6 rows of the `csv` image.

Your question is not clear.  I'm guessing you added the last 2 rows to the spread sheet, and are having problems loading those into `numpy`.  I don't see anything wrong with those numbers in the spread sheet image.  But if you show the actual csv file content, we might identify the problem.  Maybe you aren't actually writing those added rows to the csv file.

Your code sample, with corrected indentation is:

```
with open("testgrades.csv") as f:
    ncols = len(f.readline().split(','))
    nrows = sum(1 for row in f)
grades = np.loadtxt("testgrades.csv", delimiter=',', skiprows=1, usecols=range(1,ncols+1))
print(grades)
```

I can see using the `ncols` to determine the number of columns.  The `usecols` parameter needs an explicit list of columns, not some sort of `all-but-first`.  You could have also gotten that number from a plain `loadtxt` (or `genfromtxt`).

But why calculate `nrows`?  You don't appear to use it.  And it isn't needed in the `loadtxt`.  `genfromtxt` allows a `max_rows` parameter if you need to limit the number of rows read.

Answer (score -2):

Python has a special module for reading and writing CSV files [Python CSV](https://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html)

Python 2

```
import csv
with open('testgrades.csv', 'rb') as f:
```

Python 3

```
import csv
with open('testgrades.csv', newline='') as f:
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre You are absolutely right, but the original poster never mentioned the python version, and I assumed Python 2

Comment: Okay tank you so I added " with open('testgrades.csv', 'rb') as f:"
And It says = TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'?

Comment: How does this answer the question? All you do is import a module?

Comment: Sorry guys I use Python 3.5

Comment: Well It doesn't work :(  The row counter works and count the correct number of rows, but when I try to add one more row, it dosen't appear when I print the data.

Comment: You have to write the CSV file using csv.writer. Check examples at https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html

Comment: also `with open('testgrades.csv', 'r') as f:` works whatever the version. It's the write part that can be tricky.

Comment: Except for handling quoted strings, the `numpy` csv reader that the OP uses is just as good, if not better than the generic Python `csv` module.